# Access a private field from MainActivity Class to another Class

Tags: java, android

I have declared a private field in the MainActivity Class with getter and setter method. Now I want to setText from another class in this field. But after running the device the app is crushing. I want to fetch some json data by using this code. I am not getting how to call this field from another class and how to set the value to run the app smoothly. My code looks like this.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity { 
private TextView tvData;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button btnHit=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnHit);
    tvData=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvJsonItem);


    btnHit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            JSONTask jsonTask=new JSONTask("https://jsonparsingdemo-cec5b.firebaseapp.com/jsonData/moviesDemoItem.txt"); //error showing this cannot be applied
            jsonTask.execute();

        }
    });

}
```

The another class is

```
  public class JSONTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{
 private TextView tvData;

 public JSONTask(TextView tvData) {
    this.tvData =tvData;
 }

 @Override
 protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    BufferedReader reader = null;

    try {
        URL url = new URL(params[0]);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.connect();
        InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();

        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

        String line = "";

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            buffer.append(line);
        }
       return buffer.toString();


    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (connection != null) {
            connection.disconnect();
        }
        try {
            if (reader != null) {
                reader.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;
 }


 @Override
 protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    tvData.setText(result);
  }
}
```

Comment: show logcat & create static class

Comment: What you are doing is wrong. You should make other class return value into main activity then set edttext.settext(result). 
result is value return from JSONTask class

Comment: @sammie Could you please explain a bit.

Comment: you are creating new instance of your main activity that means your textView object will also initialize again , this is crashing your app--- It will be better that make a constructor of you JSONTask class pass the textView object there and make an feild also inside JSONTask. then directly setText to in postExecute method

Comment: @AjeetChoudhary I am very new in handling this case. Could you please explain more how could I do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your AsyncTask like this:

```
class JSONTask extends AsyncTask<String ,String,String>{
private TextView textView;

public JSONTask(TextView textView) {
    this.textView = textView;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    super.onPostExecute(s);
    textView.setText(s);
}
```

}

now call this class from MainActivity

```
JSONTask jsonTask = new JSONTask(yourTextView);
    jsonTask.execute();
```

Comment: I have updated my code, but it is showing an error message, which I described in the code

Comment: you have to pass TextView in constructor i.e. tvData in your case, not url:JSONTask jsonTask = new JSONTask(tvData);
    jsonTask.execute("https://jsonparsingdemo-cec5b.firebaseapp.com/jsonData/moviesDemoItem.txt");

Answer (score 0):

Hope it will work for you .

```
 @override
   protected void onPostExecute(String result){
      super.onPostExecute(result);
      new MainActivity().setTvData().setText(result);
```

Use **setTvData().setText()** to set the value if you only one data in your json string .

Comment: it is showing setTVData(Textview) in MainActivity cannot be applied

Comment: On the one hand you probably have a typo there: `setTvData()` returns void, I suppose you're talking about `getTvData()`. On the other hand this will never work, because you're updating some fresh instance of `MainActivity` This fresh instance is not (and will never be) displayed to the user. You want to update the instance of `MainActivity` to which the `AsyncTask` belongs. So you have to write `MainActivity.this` .

Comment: @hina you can try the above , it should work , or let us know so that can help you with the same .

Comment: @TaritRay I am trying in your way. But it is not actually clear to me. Hence I have updated my code. and tried in an alternative way.